# AngularJS - How to Get TemplateUrl from Controller?

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

I'm trying to access the current template URL when I change states in the template's controller.

The routes:

```
lrdcom.config(
    function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider, $locationProvider, stringUtilsProvider) {  
        $stateProvider
            .state(
                'docs',
                {
                    templateUrl: function($stateParams) {
                        return 'src/pages/' + $stateParams.doc + '.html';
                    },
                    url: '/docs/:doc'
                }
            );
    }
);
```

In the controller, I'd like to know what the templateURL actually returns:

```
pageViewer.controller(
    'pageViewerController',
    function($scope, $location, $state) {
        // how to get current url of template?
    }
);
```

As in, if the templateURL returned `src/pages/mydoc.html` how would i get that url from the controller?

I've looked at a number of SO answers suggesting accessing `$route`, or `$state` in the controller but I still cannot get it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried this yet?

> $state.current.templateurl

Otherwise do a console.log($state.current) and see if you can find your data there.

**Edit:**

I just tested it and it works, but note the capital 'U' in 'Url', so like this:

```
$state.current.templateUrl
```

Comment: You're correct that I can do that. However, I set a function for templateUrl, so getting `$state.current.templateUrl` returned a function instead of a string. To get it to work, all I had to do was pass back in `$stateParams` like so: `$state.current.templateUrl($stateParams)`. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Why not including `$stateParams` as as service for the controller and access the `doc` param in the controller and compose the url again?

```
pageViewer.controller('pageViewerController', function($scope, $location, $stateParams) {
       // how to get current url of template?
       var url = 'src/pages/' + $stateParams.doc + '.html';
    }
);
```

**Important `$stateParams` Gotcha**

In state controllers, the $stateParams object will only contain the params that were registered with that state. So you will not see params registered on other states, including ancestors.

```
$stateProvider.state('contacts.detail', {
        url: '/contacts/:contactId',   
        controller: function($stateParams){
        $stateParams.contactId  //*** Exists! ***//
}
 }).state('contacts.detail.subitem', {
      url: '/item/:itemId', 
      controller: function($stateParams){
      $stateParams.contactId //*** Watch Out! DOESN'T EXIST!! ***//
      $stateParams.itemId //*** Exists! ***//  
  }
```

})

You can also find the above example on this page [URL Routing](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/URL-Routing)

Comment: Thanks for answer. Yah in spirit of DRY, I was hoping to avoid recreating that logic and to just pull in the string from somewhere.